# Microsoft Windows Terminal Server synchronizes my local desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-server, synchronization, desktop

I'm connecting to several Windows Terminal Servers(2008 R2 Enterprise - 2012 R2 Standard). Everything worked fine until some weeks ago it took me more than one hour to connect(usually ~2-5 mins). The reason why it took so long was because it synchronized my local desktop to the Terminal Server Desktop.
Any ideas why this suddenly happened or how I can turn that off?

Comment: Have you checked the configured options in the remote desktiop connection? Maybe something has changed. Especially I would check the local ressources tab if there are any local drives selected.

Comment: Are you using roaming profiles? It sounds like you are.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes we are...we have to. But at least for 2 years it didnt decide to copy my whole desktop to the terminal server

Comment: @Kevin i have to look and check that on Monday, since I have this problem at work.